# picked image saving causes slowing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, nscoding

I picked an image from iphone by the follwing code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info  {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage *pickedImg = (UIImage*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [self.photoBtn setBackgroundImage:pickedImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[self.tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]].contentView addSubview:photoBtn];
    data.img = pickedImg;
    //data.img = nil;
    [self.tblView reloadData];
}
```

And then saving by this code:

```
-(void)saveProfile  {

    data.firstName = firstName.text;
    data.lastName = lastName.text;
    data.phoneMob = phoneMob.text;
    data.phoneHome = phoneHome.text;
    data.emailOffice = emailOff.text;
    data.emailPersonal = emailPers.text;
    data.address = address.text;
    data.company = company.text;
    data.website = website.text;
    //NSLog(data.img);

    NSMutableData *pData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

    NSString *path = [common saveFilePath];

    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc]initForWritingWithMutableData:pData];
    [data encodeWithCoder:archiver];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [pData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But when i tried to save the profile, it causes slowing.
Then i tried `data.img = nil` in the first method. now it saves without slow and withou image. How can i fasten the saving with image?

Answer (score 0):

Your main thread is being locked by the save action.  Put the code to write the image to a file in it's own thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
    NSMutableData *pData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    NSString *path = [common saveFilePath];

    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc]initForWritingWithMutableData:pData];
    [data encodeWithCoder:archiver];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [pData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
});
```

This will allow the main thread to continue while the file is being written out.

Comment: thx. but it crashes with  -[CALayer phoneMob]: unrecognized selector sent to instance